# What is the ellipsis beside a data type parameter means?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am currently studying AsyncTask.

I noticed that there is an ellipsis after the data type of the first parameter.

```
class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Bitmap>
{
   @Override
   protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... id)
   {
      Bitmap btmp = //insert some code here
      return btmp;
   }
}
```

What is that ellipsis does?

Comment: ellipses indicated n number of arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **ellipsis**  is the three dot (...) notation is actually borrowed from mathematics, and it means "...and so on".

As for its use in Java, it stands for `varargs`, meaning that any number of arguments can be added to the method call. The only limitations are that the `varargs` must be at the end of the method signature and there can only be one per method.